# Найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d, прозрачность

Если навести мышь на кнопку, то кнопка становится на 50% прозрачней. Так вот, написал я значит код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        renderer.material.color.a = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Но он не работает, в чем ошибка?

Comment: а почему этот код должен работать?

Answer (score 2):

`OnMouseEnter()` работает только с коллайдерами, которые **не** являются UI элементами и с *устаревшей* GUI системой интерфейса, которую сейчас постепенно забывают, с точки зрения Unity как движка, ее советуют не использовать, с точки зрения системы интерфейса внутри движка ее, вроде как, еще используют, но это явно не ваш случай.

На замену этому пришло 2 решения, первый - реализация интерфейса [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html):

> Interface to implement if you wish to receive OnPointerEnter
>   callbacks.
>
> Use to detect when the mouse begins to hover over a certain
>   GameObject. To detect when the mouse stops hovering over the
>   GameObject, use IPointerExitHandler.

Второй - новая систему событий, в данном случае все очень просто: выбираем событие Pointer Enter и выбираем объект, с которого будем запускать выбранный метод. [Подробнее про данную систему можно почитать здесь](http://unity-coding.slashgames.org/unitys-not-so-new-event-system/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. `GameObject.renderer` - устаревшая штука, Unity уже давно не советует использовать "шорткаты" и всегда использовать полноценный `GameObject.GetComponent<>()`.
2. `GameObject.renderer` возвращает компонент Renderer, который есть не у всех элементов графики, например, кнопка с Image (Script) компонентом использует материал, но Renderer'а нет. Вся хитрость в том, что он прикреплен к объекту Image, а не к главному объекту. Поэтому лучше самому доставать нужный компонент, а не слепо доверять `renderer`'y
3. `Material.color = ...` - это эквивалент `Material.SetProperty("_Color", ...)`, это конечно редкость, но у кастомного шейдера может и не быть параметра "_Color", так что св-во `color` - не всегда самое лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html) и проверьте, кто на вашей кнопке есть Collider, иначе событие отрабатывать не будет

Comment: В документации говорится о элементах "GUI" **и** объектах с "коллайдерами", не путайте два этих понятия, данная система событий для UI устарела.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker и еще внимательней смотрим в документацию где написано "GUIelement or Collider", из приложенного кода, очевидно, что GuiElement тут не  фигурирует

Comment: и еще внимательнее если посмотреть, то можно увидеть, что в юнити уже давно используется новая система UI - _Please Note: This component
 relates to legacy methods for drawing UI
 textures and images to the screen. You should use Unity’s up-to-date UI system instead. This is also unrelated to the IMGUI system._

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я про одно, вы про другое. Ваш ответ и комментарии предполагают, что используется Unity UI, а то, что я написал, решит проблему, если речь идет о простом Gameobject, не имеющим отношения к Unity UI

Comment: хм, справедливое замечание, почему-то из-за слова "кнопки" подумал, что речь про UI, тогда разумеется, обычный коллайдер на не UI-объекте решит проблему, если шейдер поддерживает прозрачность, разумеется

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема, вот как ее решить:

```
Color prevColor = renderer.material.color;
prevColor.a = 0.5f;
```

А все это потому, объект color – свойство. Если свойством является объект в языке c#, ты не можешь получить доступ к полям, вызывать методы этого объекта, в таких случаях обычно создают ссылку на этот объект, в нашем случае это prevColor, и дальше уже с ним работаешь. Это тоже самое, если бы ты попытался реализовать передвижение игрока вот таким вот способом:

```
player.transform.position.x += speed
```

Но это ведь не заработает,  опять нужно создать ссылку на позицию  игрока:

```
Vector3 pos = player.transform.position;
pos.x += speed;
```

– Этот пример для закрепления

Comment: Ваш способ не будет работать, prevColor и pos - это _копии_ объектов color и pos, что легко проверить следующим кодом: `Debug.Log(Object.ReferenceEquals(prevColor, renderer.material.color));`. Чтобы это заработало - нужно после всех махинаций с копией присваивать ее обратно цвету рендерера: `renderer.material.color = prevColor`.

Comment: Перепутал, точно! Интересно, а почему UnityEngine, не предоставляет именно **ссылку** на объект?

Comment: Копирование - более частое явление, нежели ссылки, если бы Unity возвращал ссылки на разделяемый объект, пришлось бы каждый раз создавать новый объект. Да и если поразмышлять о термине "игровой объект", можно прийти к выводу, что каждый такой объект должен быть единственным владельцем данных, которыми он оперирует. Если два разных объекта будут использовать один ресурс, то они, очевидно, будут друг от друга зависеть, а это не есть хорошо в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Простой пример - тот же transform.position, допустим, у нас есть два объекта: один - статичный, другой с поддержкой физики и, в том числе, гравитации, если бы они разделяли общий Vector3 Transform.position, то влияние гравитации второго объекта влияло бы на первый, а это явно неправильная логика :)